# Confusion about using moment condition in a multiple regression model

Tags: regression, moments, method-of-moments

The very simple case assumes that we have a model like $y = a + bx + e$ where the condition $cov(x,e)=0$ is true. Hence one can use the relationship of the moment conditions to estimate the parameter $b$, i.e.:

$b = \frac{cov(x,y)}{var(x)}$

The estimate of $b$ is then achieved by replacing the moment conditions by the sample ones.

Next lets assume that we have a model like $y = a + b_1*x_1 + b_2*x_2 + e$ where again the conditions $cov(x_1,e)=0$ and $cov(x_2,e)=0$ are assumed to be true.

If I now want to estimate $b_1$ and $b_2$ in the same manner I again would start with the moment conditions, i.e. with:

$cov(x_1,y) = b_1*var(x_1) + b_2*cov(x_1,x_2)$

$b_2 = \frac{cov(x_1,y) - b_2*cov(x_1,x_2)}{var(x_1)}$

For $b_1$ I'll get:

$b_1 = \frac{cov(x_2,y) - b_1*cov(x_1,x_2)}{var(x_2)}$

Now I could plug $b_1$ into the $b_2$ equation and calcuate $b_2$ in the same way we calculated $b$ before by replacing all the conditions by the sample ones.

My confusion now is due to the calculation R does with the `lm` function which yields different results. There is bound to be a mistake because the results of the first example (calculation of $b$) and the results of the `lm` function coincide.

Just for explanatory reasons I created this R code which is not necessary to understand what I would like to achieve here.

```r
n       <- 100
set.seed(100)
x1      <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
x2      <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
y       <- 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    
mod         <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
    
cov_y_x1    <- cov(y, x1)
cov_y_x2    <- cov(y, x2)
cov_x1_x2   <- cov(x1, x2)
var_x1  <- var(x1)
var_x2  <- var(x2)
    
coef(mod)[2] #(1)
    ( cov_y_x1/var_x1 - (cov_y_x2*cov_x1_x2)/(var_x2*var_x1) ) / 
               ( 1 - ((cov_x1_x2^2)/(var_x2*var_x1)) ) #(2)
    cov_y_x1/var_x1 #(3)
```

Here I already plugged the $b_1$ equation into the $b_2$ one.

Comment: Your discussion of `x1` and `x2` indicates you are thinking of them as random variables. However, you do not describe what assumptions you are making about them (are they supposed to be independent of each other? independent from one observation to the next? etc.), nor is this point of view consistent with what `lm` does.  Please, then, clarify your model by telling us explicitly what is random, what is not, and what assumptions you are making about the random variables.

Comment: Sry about that. I assumed what is done in the context of classical linear regression, i.e., that $e$ is a random variable with normal distribution which is at least asymptotically uncorrelated with the independend variables. This means that any randomness which generates the independend variable does not influence the process which is generating the $e$. Further it is assumed that the independend variables are not perfectly correlated which does obviously not exclude correlation. FYI I do not observe a time related construct just a example of cross-sectional data.

Comment: What I'm after is to simply show how high correlation does have an impact on the OLS-coefficient which is numerical equal to a method of moment estimator described earlier.

Comment: The inconsistency in your exposition is that with the use of expressions like "$cov(x_1,y)$" you are indicating quite the opposite: namely, that $x_1$ is a *random variable.* If you want to study correlation among the independent variables, why not use the usual formulas for the OLS solutions?  Then you will get correct results :-).

Comment: I kinda like the method of moments approach more. But you are right. As I remember MM in the context of linear regression we only make assumptions about the independend variables regarding $e$: one generating process which is generating the $e$'s is independend of the others which generates the $x$'s. In that sense I suppose that $x$ itself can be random and dependend on other x's. As my first example showed the parameter $b$ can be expresses as $\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(x)}$. Im not quite certain if this is true in the more generel model as well where there is more then one regressor.

Comment: I edited my previous post. What you refered to was that (1) - estimation via the lm function is numerical equal to (2) but not (3). In the context of moments of the population (1) and (3) are only true if $cov(x_1,x_2)=0$ but as far as I remember is this not a assumption in OLS.